# Nuget packages not restoring correctly when Copying and including .NET projects from one solution to another

Tags: c#, .net, class-library, csproj

I have a need to copy a .NET project / class library from one solution to another.
Does a copy/paste and subsequent inclusion of the project in the new solution suffice?

Or are there any caveats? 
(like generating a new Project GUID etc...)

The main reason I ask is because the nuget packages are not restoring and being added to references at all after I copy and include the csproj.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Sharing of binaries? Sharing of source code? Do you need one solution to be able to see changes made in the shared code by the other solution?

Comment: replication of source code. [Sharing] is not the focus.

Comment: Did you copy your packages.config?

Comment: Yes...packages.config...does exist. On restore...the dependent packages appear with an yellow-earning in the [References]. I checked the repositories.config too and that also is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, and it was because in the new Solution the NuGet Packages folder was in a different location relative to the project. To get around it I took the following steps:

1. Copy the project into the directory you want it to be in
2. Edit the csproj file so that all references to the Packages folder are correct relative to the new location
3. Add the project to the solution and build - packages will be restored